# ¿Como pasar una opción a la instancia de Tooltips en Materializecss?

Tags: javascript, css, materialize, material-design, design

Estoy utilizando la ultima version de Materializecss en donde `jquery` ya no es una dependencia del framework. Para ello estoy haciendo un `tooltips` llamando a la instancia correspondiente en mi archivo `.js` pero no se como pasarle las opciones.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
<a class="btn tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="">Hover me!</a>

<script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltipped');
        var instances = M.Tooltip.init(elems, options);
    });

</script>
```

`options` recibe un objeto, para ello intente hacer lo siguiente:

```
var options = new Object();
options.html = "<div>Hola Mundo</div>";
```

Pero no funciona. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

`options.html` html seria la opcion del plugins que quiero ocupar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

No se por que antes no me funciono, pero lo hice otra vez de la misma forma que indique en el ejemplo y quedo OK.

Dejo el código por si acaso.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltipped');
    var options = new Object();
    options.html = "<div style='background: red;'>jdskljdklsjdkl</div>";
    var instances = M.Tooltip.init(elems, options);
});
```